# wrong result in cv2.CalibrateHandEye

Tags: python, robotics, calibration

I am trying to calibrate a hand-to-eye robotic arm and camera system. I am using the cv2.CalibrateHandEye function to calculate the transform matrix between robot base and camera. But I only get wrong results.

The camera is calibrated, and I use the cv2.SolvePnp function to get the translation and rotation vector of the marker from images that took by camera, and use cv2.Rodrigues to transform the rotation vector into the rotation matrix.

The rotation matrix of end is generated using tfs.euler.euler2mat according to the rotation of end effector.

I checked both matrices many times, I think they are correct, but the cv2.CalibrateHandeye function just keep out put answers that not even close the true value.

here is some of the code.

I recorded about 20 sets of images and end pose, code below is how I extract matrix from each of them

```
(success, rvec, tvec) = cv2.solvePnP(np.array(point_3d), np.array(corners_2d), mtx, dist,flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)
R_board_in_camera = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0]
T_board_in_camera = tvec
H_board_in_camera = np.zeros((4, 4), np.float)
H_board_in_camera[:3, :3] = R_board_in_camera
H_board_in_camera[:3, 3] = np.array(T_board_in_camera).flatten()
H_board_in_camera[3, 3] = 1

R_hand_in_base = tfs.euler.euler2mat(math.radians(angle_x), math.radians(angle_y), math.radians(angle_z), axes='rxyz')
T_hand_in_base = np.array([x,y,z])  # calculated in advance

H_hand_in_base = np.zeros((4, 4), np.float)
H_hand_in_base[:3, :3] = R_hand_in_base
H_hand_in_base[:3, 3] = T_hand_in_base.flatten()
H_hand_in_base[3, 3] = 1
```

After I got all matrices, I use calibrate funcion

```
n = len(Ts_hand_to_base)
R_base_to_hand = []
T_base_to_hand = []
R_board_to_camera = []
T_board_to_camera = []

for i in range(n):
    Ts_base_to_hand = np.linalg.inv(Ts_hand_to_base[i])
    R_base_to_hand.append(np.array(Ts_base_to_hand[:3, :3]))
    T_base_to_hand.append(np.array(Ts_base_to_hand[:3, 3]))
    R_board_to_camera.append(np.array(Ts_board_to_camera[i][0, :3]))
    T_board_to_camera.append(np.array(Ts_board_to_camera[i][:3, 3]))

R_camera_to_base, T_camera_to_base = cv2.calibrateHandEye(R_base_to_hand, T_base_to_hand, R_board_to_camera,T_board_to_camera, method=cv2.CALIB_HAND_EYE_DANIILIDIS)
```

here are some of the results i get.

```
# method = cv2.CALIB_HAND_EYE_HORAUD
H_camera_to_base:
 [[  1.    -0.01  -0.04  13.54]
 [  0.    -0.96   0.29 141.48]
 [ -0.04  -0.29  -0.96   0.  ]
 [  0.     0.     0.     1.  ]]

method = cv2.CALIB_HAND_EYE_HORAUD
 [[  -0.22   -0.98   -0.01  186.04]
 [  -0.95    0.21    0.23 -187.49]
 [  -0.22    0.05   -0.97  782.4 ]
 [   0.      0.      0.      1.  ]]

method = cv2.CALIB_HAND_EYE_TSAI
 [[ 0.51 -0.3   0.8  64.88]
 [-0.54  0.62  0.57 69.03]
 [-0.67 -0.72  0.15  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    1.  ]]

method = CALIB_HAND_EYE_ANDREFF
error (-7:Iterations do not converge) Rotation normalization issue: determinant(R) is null in function 'normalizeRotation'

method = CALIB_HAND_EYE_PARK
 [[nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```